# How to create Chromosomes and Fitness function for this NP-Hard Genetic algorithm problem

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem, genetic-programming

Hi i am very new to genetic algorithm and i am stuck with this problem:

A move is provided for a student. He has to store his things in small plastic boxes in a cardboard box with a capacity of 2 cubic meters. Knowing that the small plastic boxes have the following capacities 20 cubic centimeters, 35 cubic centimeters and 60 cubic centimeters. In this genetic algorithm problem we need to find the maximum number of plastic boxes stored in this cardboard box.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to use the knapsack problem as inspiration but it didn't really work.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good question for this site.

If you have a specific issue with your code that is more specific than "it doesn't really work" then you can post your coding issue here instead.

If it is a general question about genetic algorithms then a different SE site may be more suitable, such as Stack Exchange Computer Science

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.